# Froze java process not killed by signal sigtrap

Tags: java, linux, operating-system, redhat, java-11

In my process controlling app, sigtrap signal is used to kill processes in linux environment.
When sigtrap signal received,

- running c++ processes get killed.
- froze c++(by kill -19) processes also killed.
- running java processes killed.
- but froze(by kill -19) java processes not killed.

I want to know why the froze java processes not kiled by sigtrap signal? note than process killed without another sigtrap signal if process is resumed.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, since this is only used to "show" the expected behavior here; The problem only occurs for java.

Comment: Do you know why this behaviour in a java process?

Comment: No; it's probably related to the way java works (i.e. using a jre to run the program)...

Comment: Any way to kill such frozen process without hanging in linux?